# Why did Clay tell Hannah's ghost that she did a 'bad thing'?

Tags: plot-explanation, 13-reasons-why

In Season 2 of *13 Reasons Why* (can't remember the episode), while Clay is talking to Hannah's ghost he shouts out that she did a 'bad thing' (killing herself). He was angry and sad at the time (probably spoke words out of the mouth?).

Why did he say that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Because suicide is not a solution.

Hannah killed herself and didn't give a chance to people who could have saved her, Clay loved her and didn't get a chance to do anything to save her life. So he means to say that Hannah did a bad thing killing herself.

He even asked the priest:

> **Clay:** And do you think Hannah is going to hell because she killed herself? I don't.
>
> **Priest:** I think the God I believe in, a just God, would have mercy on a soul like hers.
> And if God forgives her, we should. Source: [springfieldspringfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=13-reasons-why-2017&episode=s02e13)

So his thinking of Hannah's suicide being a bad thing can have religious backing too but in rest of the show he don't show any religious sign.